# Chrome extension: sending a variable (url) to python

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that gets the url of the pages a user visits, and from there would send it to Python where I could do things like natural language processing, etc. I would then want to send something back to be displayed in the extension popup, although I'm not completely sure what yet.

I can't figure out how to send the url to Python.

I'm *very* new at all of this so any help/insight would be appreciated! I haven't been able to find anything online that I understood about doing this.

Comment: Please provide your code what you have right now.

Comment: Right now I just have the following in a content.js file: `let current_url = window.location.href`. And the typical manifest.json file.

Comment: Study the [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) documentation and demo code linked there.